# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error : i tried setting headers to allow domains but still not working,

Tags: php, http-headers

i tried like this :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="http://localhost" />
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```

i tried putting * also, i tried running directly by opening an html file on the computer and also i tried using http://localhost/filename.php , tried /filename.html , but didnt work .

Tried below php code also(i put that above html tag) :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
?>
<html>
<head>
```

But getting error :  Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If i run directly from file, getting error :  Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Whats the solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a server setting (as far as I understand it). You can put this in an Apache (if you're running Apache) config file in the 
`<Directory>, <Location>, <Files> or <VirtualHost>` sections, or within an .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Also, * could be "http://localhost". Make sure mod_headers is enabled/installed.